# Are there alternatives to 'in such a way'?

Tags: style

Considering the sentence:

> I'd like to do ... in such a way that ... is achieved.

Does this sound wordy? If so, is there a way to streamline it?

Comment: Is there any reason you prefer not to use _in such a way that_?

Comment: @kiamlaluno these are five words where less may suffice.  Kris even found a single word to replace this.

Comment: This is not a constructive question. All the answers are equally valid.

Comment: @Matt now it's a constructive question.

Answer (score 6):

"So" should do? "I'd like to do ..., so (that) ... is achieved."

Answer (score 1):

You can directly substitute it with "in a manner that". Not much shorter, granted, but if you want to avoid repetition it may be of use to you.

> I'd like to write this sentence **in a manner that** highlights my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use "such that"

I'd like to do addition on the calculator in such a way that the addition function is achieved.

I'd like to do addition on the calculator such that the addition function is achieved.